# I am getting error while fitting the model while doing multi step forecasting for multivariate LSTM Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am using multivariate LSTM model for forecasting multistep output. My data has 7 features including the variable I want to predict which is electerical Load. I have data of around 2 years with 96 values (for every 15 minutes) per day. I am using only 1 time step( of sliding window). Validation set is of 9600 values. I am trying to forecast next day's load ( i.e. 96 values). So I took 96 in Dense layer. I gave 3D input properly as [samples, Timesteps, Features] I gave features value as 7 here. Below is my network design:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False, activation='relu', input_shape=(train_X.shape[1],train_X.shape[2]))
model.add(Dense(96))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
```

But when I run below line of model fit.

```
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=96, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

I am getting below error.

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (96,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I dont understand why it is giving such error. Please guide me to solve this error. Please let me know if you need any more info.
I also want to ask if I am giving Input for prediction correctly. See below:
This is Input file for getting prediction. This is the last value in my dataset. I am giving this as input and predicting 96 values ahead of this value.

```
print(Utestx_X.shape)
(1, 1, 7)
```

Once the model is fit, I will predict as below:

```
yhat = model.predict(Utestx_X)
Utestx_X = Utestx_X.reshape((Utestx_X.shape[0], Utestx_X.shape[2]))
```

Comment: What is the shapes of your training data? If I understand your problem correctly train_X should be (N, 1, 7) and train_Y (N, 96) where N Is the number of samples.

Comment: Thanks for reply Sir. But my train_Y is (N,), do we need 96 columns there?

Comment: Because the output of your network is a 96-dimensional vector.

Comment: So my train daatset has 679 columns for 7 features as: (96*7) + 7(of prev time lag) = 679. Then I dropped last 6 columns which I don't want to forecast. Now I am left with train dataset as: (N, 673). Then I split it as: train_X, train_y = train[:, :7], train[:, 7]. Please guide me here. How shall I split it? I am taking features = 7 here while splitting train and test. I think that is not right.  Please tell me, how shall I split my train_X and train_Y from training data set "train", which has the shape (N, 673). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, Bjorn, when I increased the size of train_Y as (N,96), that step is running now, instead of giving the error. Here I directly gave train_Y value as: train_X, train_y = train[:, :7], train[:, 7:103] . But I think this 7:103 is not correct one. I think I should take all those 96 columns of my desired forecast variabls (columns) instead of directly 7 to 103. I think I should take columns like: 7, 15,23,...etc. Please guide me here. Thanks for showing the direction.